# Topic is created on cloud pub/sub but unable to create watch on that topic

Tags: cloud, gmail-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to create watch on cloud pub/sub topic but unable to create it. For that I'm using the rest request

```
request_Req.post({

url:'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/watch',
headers:{
   'content-type': 'application/json',
   'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ access_token,
},
scope : [
    'https://mail.google.com/'
],

'body': JSON.stringify({
    'topicName' : "/projects/ProjectId/topics/TopicId",
    'labelIds' : ["INBOX"] 
});
}),function(error, resp, body){

});
```

But I'm getting the error message `Error sending test message to Cloud 
PubSub/projects/ProjectID/topics/TopicId : Resource not found        resource=TopicId`

Comment: Does that topic exist?

Comment: Look like scopes issue try to add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

Comment: Hi gcbirzan, Yes that topic is present.I have checked it .

Comment: Hi  Raúl Martín , I have added  'https://mail.google.com/',            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly' these scopes in request still getting same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Google Cloud Pubsub topic must exist in the same Google Console project, which is being used to authenticate the users. Check /projects/**ProjectId**/topics/**TopicId** your project in Google Console and make sure the Pubsub Topic exists. Also, you must grant access to Gmail services to publish messages to your Pubsub topic via following request:

```
POST "https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1beta2/{resource=/projects/**ProjectId**/topics/**TopicId**}:setIamPolicy"
Content-type: application/json

{
  "policy": {
    "bindings": [{
      "role": "roles/pubsub.publisher",
      "members": ["serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com"],
    }],
  }
}
```

If gmail is not granted the access to publish the message to Pubsub topic, watch request wont be created. Try [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/pubsub/v1beta2/pubsub.projects.topics.setIamPolicy) to set the permissions.

Comment: Hi Furhan Shabir, I have not set grant access policy.I was trying this post request but getting error as   <p>The requested URL <code>/v1beta2/%7Bresource=projects/ProjectId/topics/TopicId%7D:setIamPolicy</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

Comment: For that my rest request is : url:  "https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1beta2/{resource=projects/myproject/topics/mytopic}:setIamPolicy",
   headers:{
       'content-type': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +                           iObj.credentials.access_token,
   },
  body : JSON.stringify({
       "policy": {
         "bindings": [{
           "role": "roles/pubsub.publisher",
           "members": ["serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com"],
         }],
       }
     
              })

Comment: @AnuPandit The request should be made to https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/topics/YOUR_PUBSUB_TOPIC_NAME:setIamPolicy

Comment: Thanks i have successfully created watch on cloud topic.But how i will get notification of mails? E.g: https://example.com/mychannel/ on this i am pulling subscription request.But i am not getting notification on '/mychannel' .on what i will get notification?

Comment: Pull is not recommended with Watch because that defeats the purpose of watch request. However, if you still want to PULL messages from pubsub, first create a subscription to the Topic you've created by using Pubsub API or Google Developer Console. https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects/subscriptions/create

You would need a service account credentials to pull this off under the same Google Console project as you used to create the topic.

Comment: Sorry , Actually i am using push request on endpoint url. But still i am not getting any notification on that url. How to get notify about mails ?

Comment: Use google cloud monitoring to see if you have undelivered messages. Its accessible on Google Developer Console. Make sure that you've created a push subscription to the Pubsub Topic in Gmail is publishing messages. It should be a publicly accessible Uri and you must process the messages received in a proper manner i.e. return 200 OK responses to dequeue messages from Pubsub Topic.

Comment: Furhan Shabir, I am setting watch on different account still i am getting updates of 1st account on which i have set watch.

Comment: @AnuPandit Call Stop() method on previous user for which you want to stop notifications otherwise as per API docs, watch will automatically expire in 7 days. 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/stop

Comment: Furhan Shabir ,I can't set  watches on different account at a time ?I want updates of all accounts on which i have set watch.But i am getting update of 1st account on which i have set watch?

Comment: (In case you didn't figure it out already) Yes, you definitely can /watch many different Gmail accounts at the same time.  Just create a single Cloud Pub/Sub Topic (and subscription) then call /watch on each Gmail user and pass the same Pub/Sub topic for each of them, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the information guys, I have successfully managed to setup watch and configured push subscription to a url end-point. Whenever I make changes to inbox I get a post on my server end-point but the post request is blank. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the topic is created AND make sure you've correctly setIamPolicy on it.  Do NOT use API explorer on it as advised by other answer.  Do those Cloud Pub/SUb calls as it says in the guide (using your own service-account client) :
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Comment: Hi Eric DeFriez, I am getting error while setting policy. Is anything missing in that request .

Comment: What is the error you get when calling setIamPolicy?

Comment: may I ask how this was solved? what does the final setiampolicy call look like? Does it link to a .json file containing the permissions or is it all in the same file?